# how to fix parse exception in application.yml file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

i have used application.yml file to write the configuration but getting problem error while running the program.

```
spring:
  application:
   name: authserver
  datasource:
   driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
   url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/USERSERVICE?autoreconnect=true"
   username: "root"
   password:
config:
 oauth2:
  clientid: client
  clientSecret: secret
  privateKey: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAwbzfuEhjYdXhZJhQB6AQw854fV6Dfs42si2Oo2sxvqrV1+2Y
  O4INlBLAIpBMKYjYugInSWlh9PZBNdilvvuynH+S1XBEKPv1iOHIhqL4S6CRh8MV
  5qsNglrGjr3LiGgNqdIh/KELjb0hfVXIfirUhFm15oJsAJKFznZwOj5AO084Q1po
  JRuPqWUlx8d+Ilf3QPMUBEvKqAigRSM1U4U17cnT/QVjH0w2g7sfU7U4bByUXhHT
  12dJev+L/+yBjFUquvdQQSIiXFxyXAcCHw5UnuBijwPAXvtrS6WaC6Bu95SdzbdS
  +q5TiKDXTDGzE8cNBm0nlRouypEMy/9j7P2gaQIDAQABAoIBAQCfOkNI6z27ABTy
  H3jO+5ArzfsbVt2OD5/Gi0jLKOPGiBOfFyhh6D6Or2Z4Qc5G6LDvF6wAWvtmYCoy
  Pi/jKmye0P72KwHqCULA0IiFl1Womnxhb0YFwholQ8QjNvwbzSFFrG3Aev/K62Gl
  6CYTA9KMQEsO+6wWQFZ23MLaK6WQ19mGnjjKlrmbHfQxIA2SLxaBYSaNlGpH85eE
  qDOGVlX+1z37ausGhcRGRMszSVgqX5YszFaaVzu2HDYC6J7nA+aq/2NuwIW9Nofc
  qmAPAIIhNWmMOzF1aD1Ao7f3JKBrqWEN7SupnbOVglm7fVmLQ8n9Af+rKRU85HMD
  MV4cBOxdAoGBAOunKe93gjUtb1GQ2V4yIimIUH8sKynzAOa+No6gHI6SgqoM65r5
  2Y9/iIue01ymP9qTDB6o5qIT5FoNe35Kz27LflpQrgpH+sKNt0+9CsAVA2LWH+jU
  3x7Sd1ZuQoWUdtupncgv6Yx5A0zvXijrUQruex2Jdwnss+UJc10Bhe/zAoGBANJ3
  OShWdDp5kSOzM1AMvirpcXYpVXv7BAeRGzMAOWUjxNfJkfuVby3X97r4FFmebLbE
  uO8Sf/Wy4C8MGUvEMSjZ3upq9juc4D05eLb7VioLPcuqoMp7D1NAXaugKJ7gTRj7
  klO1SMavPQsS63+VvFkwhbIrkpB5kmJ98rIPvaEzAoGASh5g1T3siVdKDQiXJcZ0
  8kU6tFUrGl2hKfIn7MI1WS6BxISd0jfFkxnU071X02tC6DeZ90a+i7nf9+cHsZhM
  GBgPHM8FfpxXJbw3LPBToki5sOuSS8QwjVw7RscVSziADeUSiHVxasphHGCpaAtj
  iSGrPYYQF+IITwCi9VzWSLsCgYAYq4T1p3ykRg+vQZgoL/YyjX6RPTMZ/0hvoqCv
  j70qj9DJAoWsGc4Yb5JIRkAMaTeRDOooi+CX6knA+ggVC4A/q5onnDYUssTOKGhv
  +nIVJ5AsyWljkp0vQwI31eQtC1m+Le7vBPbs4yminKsiH2keg0OIqPbbHIT+KolC
  OfoeZQKBgENmwzwT7f2HOx91X+9qDLSuFgeJXPD/pLzOgryyhTfYIN3rZ6Vf9YfJ
  CAUfDL+8aNl2mOYc3z31x3tpeV3OlSm/4FCaPzcHqEhQbPIy1hndW9rV+kQW6fX4
  2RaUgdAq4TE8t+WHk/mTue1wwKl3eL+G+0CpWHN3OZ3OWj0Himln
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  publicKey: -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
  MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwbzfuEhjYdXhZJhQB6AQ
  w854fV6Dfs42si2Oo2sxvqrV1+2YO4INlBLAIpBMKYjYugInSWlh9PZBNdilvvuy
  nH+S1XBEKPv1iOHIhqL4S6CRh8MV5qsNglrGjr3LiGgNqdIh/KELjb0hfVXIfirU
  hFm15oJsAJKFznZwOj5AO084Q1poJRuPqWUlx8d+Ilf3QPMUBEvKqAigRSM1U4U1
  7cnT/QVjH0w2g7sfU7U4bByUXhHT12dJev+L/+yBjFUquvdQQSIiXFxyXAcCHw5U
  nuBijwPAXvtrS6WaC6Bu95SdzbdS+q5TiKDXTDGzE8cNBm0nlRouypEMy/9j7P2g
  aQIDAQAB-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

i have used application.yml for writing configuration but when the application is run, i am getting "org.yaml.snakeyaml.scanner.ScannerException: while scanning a simple key
 in 'reader', line 15, column 5:"error in console

Comment: https://prnt.sc/oz83sl here is the screenshot of error

Comment: Hint: don't. Pasting private key in application.properties is suicidal.

Comment: you can either keep it as a file in the resources folder or can get from the system environment, use application.yml for specifying the path to the corresponding location.

Answer (score 4):

You can fix parse exception by writing correct YAML file.

For multiline strings preserving new lines you could use block literal style:

```
property: |
  This is
  some string with new lines
  preserved in YAML.
```

You can check [here](https://yaml-multiline.info) for details.

But as @Andronicus pointed out, private keys do not belong in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Povide the syntax like this :

```
   privateKey: |
            -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

            -----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```